# Libreoffice Calc - how to drag cell leaving formula in original cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Is there a way/setting to leave the formatting in a specific cell after using 'cut' or dragging the content of the cell away?

'Protecting' the cell is not what I'm looking for since that disables also the editing of the cell. Also 'paste special' is not an option because I switch contents a lot.

Perfect would be a setting where you can deselect 'remove formatting original cell' when using cut or drag.

Comment: When you cut or drag away cell contents, the cell reverts to the "default" format.  Have you considered editing the "default" format (Format→Styles and Formatting) to the properties you want?

Comment: @Lyrl This is genius and exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Now I can put text in a cell or when it's a number it changes it automatically to a currency, saves a big-lot of time, perfect!